Correct syntax for powershell python based json config changes
I am trying to change the config of this python program that I got from Git Hub, https://github.com/KraXen72/shira.
I am running this program on powershell. However when I try to add the location of the cookies file I am getting an error. I believe this is an syntax error.
Please help me correct the syntax if you know what I am doing wrong. I tried so many combinations without any help.
Thanks in advance.
I tried to edit other config on the scripts. But no help. I also tried multiple combination of syntax that I know of. again no help. I also manually edited the json file. However that broke the app. so I changed it back. I understand this is probably a very noob question. But I am new to programming trying to learn these thihngs.
I want to see the right way of editing these
Thanks
PS C:\Users\Anuvind\shira> python -m shiradl -c --cookies-location/ C:\Users\Anuvind\Desktop\Music\Cookies\youtube.com_cookies

[CRITICAL 14:53:42] Cookies file not found at "--cookies-location"

PS C:\Users\Anuvind\shira> python -m shiradl -c --cookies-location C:\Users\Anuvind\Desktop\Music\Cookies\youtube.com_cookies

[CRITICAL 14:53:50] Cookies file not found at "--cookies-location"


-c is a shorthand for --cookies-location - use one or the other, not both:
PS ~> python -m shiradl --cookie-location C:\Users\Anuvind\Desktop\Music\Cookies\youtube.com_cookies
# or 
PS ~> python -m shiradl -c C:\Users\Anuvind\Desktop\Music\Cookies\youtube.com_cookies

